# How do I build a Django model that retrieves some fields from an API?

Tags: python, django

#### Question

How can I build a Model that that stores one field in the database, and then retrieves other fields from an API behind-the-scenes when necessary?

#### Details:

I'm trying to build a Model called `Interviewer` that stores an ID in the database, and then retrieves `name` from an external API. I want to avoid storing a copy of `name` in my app's database. I also want the fields to be retrieved in bulk rather than per model instance because these will be displayed in a paginated list.

My first attempt was to create a custom Model Manager called `InterviewManager` that overrides `get_queryset()` in order to set `name` on the results like so:

```
class InterviewerManager(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self):
    query_set = super().get_queryset()

    for result in query_set:
      result.name = 'Mary'

    return query_set

class Interviewer(models.Model):  
  # ID provided by API, stored in database
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)

  # Fields provided by API, not in database
  name = 'UNSET'

  # Custom model manager
  interviewers = InterviewerManager()
```

However, it seems like the hardcoded value of `Mary` is only present if the QuerySet is not chained with subsequent calls. I'm not sure why. For example, in the django shell:

```
>>> list(Interviewer.interviewers.all())[0].name
'Mary'   # Good :)
>>> Interviewer.interviewers.all().filter(id=1).first().name
'UNSET'  # Bad :(
```

My current workaround is to build a cache layer inside of `InterviewManager` that the model accesses like so:

```
class InterviewerManager(models.Manager):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.api_cache = {}

  def get_queryset(self):
    query_set = super().get_queryset()

    for result in query_set:
      # Mock querying a remote API
      self.api_cache[result.id] = {
        'name': 'Mary',
      }

    return query_set

class Interviewer(models.Model):  
  # ID provided by API, stored in database
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)

  # Custom model
  interviewers = InterviewerManager()

  # Fields provided by API, not in database
  @property
  def name(self):
    return Interviewer.interviewers.api_cache[self.id]['name']
```

However this doesn't feel like idiomatic Django. Is there a better solution for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: In your first attempt. I think you should also call result.save() in order to actually apply the changes that were made to the model instance.

Comment: @VishalAsthana: Good idea. I tried but it had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

why not just make the API call in the `name` property?

```py
@property
def name(self):
    name = get_name_from_api(self.id)
    return name
```

Comment: I should have been clearer: this model will be displayed in a list form, so I’d like to make just a single API call for one page of results rather than one call per row of Interviewers.

Answer (score 0):

If that isnt possible by manipulating a get request where you can add a list of names and recieve the data. The easy way is to do it is in a loop.

I would recommand you to build a so called proxy where you load the articles in a dataframe/dict, save this varible data ( with for example pickle ) and use it when nessary. It reduces loadtimes and is near efficient.